We know existence of Transcendental raised to Algebraic Irrational equals rational, but what about opposite?
Introduction:
If we take $a=2^\sqrt[3]{2}$ which is transcendental by Gelfond-Schneider Theorem, and $b=\sqrt[3]{4}$ which is algebraic irrational because it is root of monic-irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $3$ which is $x^{3}-4$.(The polynomial is irreducible by the theorem: If polynomial in $F[x]$ where $F$ is field has degree $2$ or $3$ and doesn't have roots in $F$, then it is irreducible over $F$ ).
So, there exist transcendental $a$ and algebraic irrational $b$ such that $a^{b}$ is rational.
My question: Can the opposite happen, i.e, there exist algebraic irrational $a$ and transcendental b, such that $a^{b}$ is rational?

Yes. Let $a=\sqrt{2}$. By the intermediate value theorem, there is some $0<x<1$, for which $\sqrt{2}^x$ is rational. $x$ can not be rational, and, by Gelfond-Schneider, it can not be algebraic either so it must be transcendental.  (As in the comments you can solve for $x$ if you want, but you don’t need to.)

Your solution is smart and beneficial, thanks!

The following is just discussion, so irrational to irrational is rational in the following cases:

Transcendental to algebraic irrational, one of the examples is the one I mentioned in the body of my question.

2)Algebraic irrational to transcendental, one of the examples is in your answer, one specific example is the solution to $(\sqrt{2})^{x}=\frac{7}{5}$, $x=2*\frac{ln(\frac{7}{5})}{ln(2)}$.

Transcendental to Transcendental, one of the examples is $e^{ln(2)}$.

Note, Algebraic irrational to Algebraic irrational is not included by Gelfond-Schneider Theorem.

You have not worked out why $x$ cannot be rational , and it is not at all obvious.

@Peter Consider a rational in reduced form, then $\sqrt{2}^{p/q}$ being rational must mean that $2^p$ is a $2q$-th perfect power, so $q$ divides $p$, meaning that $p$ is an integer….
